# Batch file processing with spaces and periods in a filename

Tags: batch-file, filenames

I am trying to process multiple SQL scripts into a single file. However, I am having issues as I do not have control over their naming. I also need to specify the file rather than processing them all from the folder.

Example code below. I cannot get it to process files with periods and spaces in.

```
SET destination=%cd%\Database.sql
SET ddlDirectory=%cd%\Test\

ECHO Destination file: %destination%
ECHO DDL directory: %ddlDirectory%

FOR /f "usebackq tokens=* delims=," %%f IN (
`%ddlDirectory%02. Create Schemas.sql`,
`%ddlDirectory%03. Create Tables.sql`)
) DO (

    @ECHO. >> %destination%
    @ECHO. >> %destination%
    @ECHO --********************************************************************** >> %destination%
    @ECHO -- Contents of file: %%f >> %destination%
    @ECHO --********************************************************************** >> %destination%

    TYPE %%f >> %destination%
)

pause
```

Any assistance appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are trying to **execute** a command `02.` in folder `%cd%\test\` without extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not quite clear if the destiantion should be cleared initially with a `type NUL >%destination%`.

```
SET destination=%cd%\Database.sql
SET ddlDirectory=%cd%\Test\

ECHO Destination file: %destination%
ECHO DDL directory: %ddlDirectory%

(FOR %%A IN (
  "%ddlDirectory%02. Create Schemas.sql"
  "%ddlDirectory%03. Create Tables.sql"
  ) DO (
    @ECHO.
    @ECHO.
    @ECHO --**********************************************************************
    @ECHO -- Contents of file: %%A
    @ECHO --**********************************************************************
    TYPE %%A
  )
) >> %destination%
pause
```

Comment: With a few tweaks this is working as i wanted it to. The "" seemed to be what i was doing wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest following batch file for this task:

```
@echo off
if "%CD:~-1%" == "\" (
    set "destination=%CD%Database.sql"
    set "ddlDirectory=%CD%Test"
) else (
    set "destination=%CD%\Database.sql"
    set "ddlDirectory=%CD%\Test"
)

echo Destination file: "%destination%"
echo DDL directory:    "%ddlDirectory%"

del "%destination%" 2>nul
set "FirstFile=yes"
for %%I in ("%ddlDirectory%\*.sql") do (

    if not defined FirstFile (
        echo/>>"%destination%"
        echo/>>"%destination%"
    ) else set "FirstFile="

    echo -- **********************************************************************>>"%destination%"
    echo -- Contents of file: %%~fI>>"%destination%"
    echo -- **********************************************************************>>"%destination%"

    type "%%I" >>"%destination%"
)

pause
```

Please note that the order of *.sql files processed by the **FOR** loop as used here depends on the file naming order of the file system. On NTFS drivers the file name order is alphabetic (more or less) whereas on FAT32 and exFAT drives the file name order depends on last write access in directory.

The same batch file with a list of file names specified in the **FOR** loop instead of processing all *.sql files in the folder.

```
@echo off
if "%CD:~-1%" == "\" (
    set "destination=%CD%Database.sql"
    set "ddlDirectory=%CD%Test"
) else (
    set "destination=%CD%\Database.sql"
    set "ddlDirectory=%CD%\Test"
)

echo Destination file: "%destination%"
echo DDL directory:    "%ddlDirectory%"

del "%destination%" 2>nul
set "FirstFile=yes"
for %%I in (
    "02. Create Schemas.sql"
    "03. Create Tables.sql"
) do (

    if exist "%ddlDirectory%\%%~I" (
        if not defined FirstFile (
            echo/>>"%destination%"
            echo/>>"%destination%"
        ) else set "FirstFile="

        echo -- **********************************************************************>>"%destination%"
        echo -- Contents of file: "%ddlDirectory%\%%~I">>"%destination%"
        echo -- **********************************************************************>>"%destination%"

        type "%ddlDirectory%\%%~I" >>"%destination%"
    )
)

pause
```

A file existing check is made before writing file name into the destination text file.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `cmd /?` ... `cmd.exe` is the Windows command processor executing a batch file. On last help page is explained that a file name with space or one of these characters `` &()[]{}^=;!'+,`~ `` must be enclosed in double quotes.
- `echo /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`
- `pause /?`
- `set /?`
- `type /?`

Please note that a space left to redirection operator `>>` on redirected **ECHO** command lines is written as trailing space into the text file.

See also DosTips forum topic: [ECHO. FAILS to give text or blank line - Instead use ECHO/](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=774)